# Concatenating files from rawvideo

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video

I used Adobe After Effects to create a basic ~10 second outro for a video, and exported it to lossless AVI format (`rawvideo`). As far as I know there is no way to give the video an empty audio stream in After Effects, and FFmpeg's concat demuxer requires each video stream to have an audio stream, so I ran the following to add some silence and re-encode the `rawvideo` to `h264`/`opus`:

```
ffmpeg -i "YouTube Outro.avi" -f lavfi -i aevalsrc=0 -map 0 -map 1 -shortest -c:v libx264 -c:a libopus "Outro.mkv"
```

The problems come when I try to concatenate this file to my original video. I have the following in a file:

```
file Original.mkv
file 'YouTube Outro.mkv'
```

Info on these inputs:

```
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Original.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.65.100
  Duration: 00:42:45.54, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 2521 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709/unknown/unknown, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR
 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.115.102 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:42:45.541000000
    Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : SoundHandler
      VENDOR_ID       : [0][0][0][0]
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.115.102 libopus
      DURATION        : 00:42:45.368000000
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'YouTube Outro.mkv':
  Metadata:
    DATE            : 2021-03-10T23:13:19.647059
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.65.100
  Duration: 00:00:08.97, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 74 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High 4:4:4 Predictive), yuv444p(tv, progressive), 1920x1080, 29.97 fps, 29.
97 tbr, 1k tbn, 59.94 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.115.102 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:00:08.949000000
    Stream #1:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.115.102 libopus
      DURATION        : 00:00:08.968000000
At least one output file must be specified
```

...and use the `concat` demuxer to concatenate them:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i list.txt -c copy Final.mkv
```

The resultant file contains the whole of the original video, and its timestamp reflects the added 10 seconds, but when that timestamp is reached nothing is shown - in fact, the video freezes a few frames before the original video ends, and remains stuck on that frame all the way to the end of the video's duration.

What am I doing wrong here that it's so hard to concatenate these `h264`/`opus` files?

Comment: Show the complete log of `ffmpeg -i Original.mkv -i "YouTube Outro.mkv"`.

Comment: @llogan [There you go](https://pastebin.com/MjdqMhAT).

Comment: For next time please always include the **complete** log if you want to avoid potential delays in answers. Yours was trimmed and missing the build info which is often important.

Comment: @llogan My bad, I had forgotten I had `ffmpeg -hide_banner` set as an alias, I find it way too verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Attributes must be the same](https://video.stackexchange.com/a/32603) for proper concatenation with the [concat demuxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat). Pixel format, profile, and channel layout vary between your inputs. Make them match `Original.mkv`:

```
ffmpeg -i "YouTube Outro.avi" -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=48000 -map 0 -map 1 -c:v libx264 -crf 18 -vf format=yuv420p -c:a libopus -shortest "Outro.mkv"
```

Comment: Wow, I didn't realise the list of things that needed to be the same was so long. Is this also true for the concat protocol? As I had also tried that and it failed too. I'll test this as soon as possible and check back.

Comment: @HashimAziz The concat protocol is too simplistic for most common formats used by the majority of general users. You can most likely ignore it.

Comment: @HashimAziz `-crf 18` was added for quality because I assumed you are uploading to YouTube which re-encodes everything you give it. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264 - CRF](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#crf).

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you once again.